# Left Join with all rows from the left not matching the Where Clause

Tags: sql, mysql

I have the following problem:

I have an account table and an entries for account table.
    account_id
    account_name

```
entry_id
account_idfk
entry_date
entry_amount
```

Now I want to query all entries for all accounts in a given period. Eg. I want all Entries for all accounts from October 2008 - October 2009. If there are no entries for this account at all, or there are only entries in other timeperiods for this account, I want the account returned as well.

My current query works, if there are no entries at all, or there are entries for this timeperiod for this account. However - it leaves out the Accounts which have only entries for other timeperiods.

```
SELECT * FROM Account a
         LEFT JOIN Entries e ON e.account_idfk = a.account_id
         WHERE e.entry_date BETWEEN '2009-08-13' AND '2009-08-13'
               OR e.entry_date IS NULL
```

I know that the problem is in the where clause - I eliminate all Accounts for which only entries in other time periods exist.

But I have no idea how to restate the query to get the desired result...

Thanks,
Martin

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Move that condition to the `join`:

```
SELECT
    * 
FROM 
    Account a
    LEFT JOIN Entries e ON 
        e.account_idfk = a.account_id
        AND e.entry_date BETWEEN '2009-08-13' AND '2009-08-13'
```

What you see here is the difference between a `join` and a `where` condition. The `join` will only join rows that meet that condition. However, with a `left join`, you still return all the rows in the left table. With the `where` clause, you're filtering rows *after* the join. In this case, you only want to join entries where the date is 8/13/09 (or 13/8/09, for those across the pond), but you want to return all accounts. Therefore, the condition needs to go into the `join` clause, and not the `where`.

This often gets confused with any outer join, because with an `inner join`, the result is the same no matter if the condition is in the `join` or `where` clause. However, this does not mean that they are equivalent, as demonstrated by you today!

Comment: Hi Eric! Thanks a lot for that quick response, thats great!
I did not know that I could have conditions on the JOIN as well - thats exactly what I needed!